# View controller transition when in-call status bar is visible

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, ios8, presentviewcontroller

I have two viewcontrollers that use

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
view.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleHeight
```

Everything is working fine, when the in-call status bar is toggled the view is smoothly resizing its height.

But when the in-call status bar is visible and the second view controller is presented via

```
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with

```
modalTransitionStyle = .FlipHorizontal
```

the presenting view jumps 20 points down and at the end of the transition the presented view jumps 20 points up (to the correct position).
How could I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Have you solve this issues? I am also facing the same issue.